# Information not updating in one of my components?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a profile component which is a tab screen, and here is the code:

```
class Profile extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            user: this.props.user,
            bio: "",
            storage_image_uri: '',
            postCount: 0,
            followerCount: 0,
            followingCount: 0,
            isLoading: true,
            navigation: this.props.navigation,
            userUID: Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
            userPostsArray: []
        }

        this.firestoreRef = 
        Firebase.firestore()
        .collection('globalPosts')
        .where("uid", "==", this.state.userUID)
        .orderBy("date_created", "desc");
        
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.pullUserInfo()
        this.unsubscribe = this.firestoreRef.onSnapshot(this.getCollection);
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.unsubscribe();
    }

    

    getCollection = (querySnapshot) => {
        const userPostsArray = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
        const { 

              ...

             } = res.data();

            userPostsArray.push({
             
            ...

                
            });
        });

        this.setState({
            userPostsArray,
            isLoading: false,   
        });

        this.pullUserInfo()
    }

    pullUserInfo = async() => {

        await Firebase.firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(this.state.userUID)
        .onSnapshot(function(doc){
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log("pulling info")
                this.setState({
                    postCount: doc.data().postCount,
                    followerCount: doc.data().followerCount,
                    followingCount: doc.data().followingCount,
                    storage_image_uri: doc.data().profilePic,
                    bio: doc.data().bio,
                    isLoading: false
                })
            } else {
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }.bind(this))
    } 

    gotToSettings() {
        this.state.navigation.navigate('Settings')
    }

    //How I show my profile stats, follower, following, bio, profile pic
    renderListHeader = () => {
        return (
            <View style = {styles.container}>


                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", padding: 20 }}>
                    <Text style = {styles.subheader}> {this.state.user.username} </Text>
                </View>
                
                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',}}>
                    <ProfilePic storage_image_uri = {this.state.storage_image_uri} /> 
                    <ProfileStats postCount = {this.state.postCount} followerCount = {this.state.followerCount} followingCount = {this.state.followingCount}/>
                </View>

                <View style = {styles.lineStyle} /> 

                <ProfileBio bio = {this.state.bio}/>

                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => this.gotToSettings()}>
                    <Ionicons name="ios-settings" size={35} color="black" />
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>

        )
    }

    render() {

        const { navigation } = this.props;
        const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    
            <CurrentUserPostCell 
            ...
            />
        );

        if(this.state.isLoading){
            return(
              <View styles = {styles.container}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E"/>
              </View>
            )
        }    
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.userPostsArray}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.key}
                    ListHeaderComponent={this.renderListHeader}
                    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 50 }}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                />
            </View>   
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see, when the component mounts, `pullUserInfo()` is called, as well as the collection of user posts is fetched. There is no issue here getting this information for the first time.

My problem is, when I post something new, or follow someone new, the post count and following count goes up respectively in Firestore. But the new numbers are not reflected in my profile.

It is worth noting, when I create a new post, the new post is displayed in on the user profile. But even this event does not update `pullUserInfo()`

So, the information is not updating. Furthermore, when I click on the profile tab, I get the following warning:

```
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method
```

How can I fix this, so that if the user information in Firestore changes, the changes update in the profile?

EDIT: I partly fixed my problem by adding "pull down to refresh" logic to the flatlist, since the flatlist header is the user profile information, and the flatlist data is the list of user posts.

At the end of flatlist in my render():

```
 return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.userPostsArray}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.key}
                ListHeaderComponent={this.renderListHeader}
                contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 50 }}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                onRefresh={this._refresh}
                refreshing={this.state.isLoading}
            />
        </View>   
    )
```

Outside the render:

```
_refresh = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    this.pullUserInfo()
};
```

This doesn't solve the full problem of the profile component only mounting once, therefore not refreshing the user stats automatically. The user has to manually pull down to refresh their profile if they want to see an updated bio, follower/following count, etc.

Comment: Try adding a property `extraData={this.state}` in your Flatlist.

Comment: @KishanBharda was hoping that would work. Still have to pull down to refresh. Tried adding extraData={this.pullUserInfo} as well, neither worked.